# Read integer data out from dictionary and do a simple calculation

Tags: ios, swift, nsdictionary

I am coding in Swift.

I have created an `NSMutableDictionary`, I store integer data inside, and save the dictionary to file:

```
var myDict : NSMutableDictionary

//store Int value
let num : Int = 6
myDict.setValue(num, forKey: “num”)

//save myDict to file
myDict.writeToFile(FILE_PATH, atomically: false)
```

Then, I have another method to read the dictionary data out from file:

```
let myDictFromFile = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: FILE_PATH)
//force cast to Int
let num = myDictFromFile?.valueForKey(“num”) as! Int

//COMPILER ERROR: Could not find an overload for ‘+’ that accepts the supplied arguments
let result: Double = num * 30.0 + num * 60.0
```

Why I get the compiler error above? How to get rid of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swift doesn't support such implicit conversions, so you'll have to explicitly convert that yourself.
try this

```
let result: Double = Double(num) * 30.0 + Double(num) * 60.0
```

Comment: yeah in this answer, we are casting on calculation time.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to do cast in this safe way:

```
if let num = myDictFromFile?.valueForKey("num") as? Double {
   let result = num * 30.0 + num * 60.0
}
```

In this way, if dictionary element for key "num" is not a Double, app does not crash and doesn't have an unexpected behaviour.